# Highcharts: using Google Analytics to capture event actions for exporting the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-analytics, data-visualization

Has anyone had success tracking events in Google Analytics when a user exports a Highcharts visualization as a PDF, PNG, etc.?

I set up a test fiddle (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/00wrak9v/) to try out the interactions with an existing website I manage that's using the universal Google Analytics script.

My problem is that none of the interactions are showing up in my Google Analytics dashboard, either under "Campaigns" or "Goals." The console log isn't showing any obvious errors, and I don't have any browser plug-ins that are blocking the fiddle from talking with Google. I've waited the suggested 24 hours for events to show up in the dashboard to no avail.

Here's a piece of the code I'm using. I'm defining my own export methods using the `menuItems` attribute. I have the GA tracking script defined elsewhere in the fiddle.

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: { text: 'Export',
                menuItems: [{
                    text: 'Print this chart',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.print();
                        console.log('chart was printed');
                        thisTitle = this.options.title.text;
                        newTitle = thisTitle.replace("<br>",": ");
                        newTitle = thisTitle.replace("<br />",": ");
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Highcharts', 'print', newTitle + ' | ' + document.title);
                    }
                }, 
                ...
```

One thing I uncovered in some searching was setting up event tracking in the Google Analytics admin console (see http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-google-analytics-event-tracking-in-wordpress/). Is that necessary to capture these types of events?

I truly appreciate any guidance you all can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on this question (for those who may come across this page in the future), the answer is, **yes, you do need to manually set up goals in Google Analytics in order for this to work**. The events I set up to track will not show up in the Campaigns section, as I had originally thought.

Here's a screenshot of the Goals section, which lives in the Admin part of the GA console. The four events I set up after I wrote my question are shown below.

[image]

What I did here was create custom goals. In the goal description, I gave each goal a unique name and chose the type "event."

[image]

For the goal details, I set the category and action as defined in my Highcharts chart options (see my question above). I left "Label" blank, as I chose to fill in my chart's title (as well as the HTML title of the page it lives on). I did not define anything for "Value," as I'm not weighting my goals.

[image]

Once these goals were created, I did finally pull in some data, but there was a few hours of lag time from when I conducted my tests to when the information showed up in the GA console.

Here's what this will look like in the Reporting section. You want to go to "Conversions," then "Goals," and finally "Goal Flow."

[image]

I hope all of this information, both the question and the answer, are helpful and useful to someone out there.

**Update (May 19, 2016)**: Yay! Data has started to come in successfully! Here's how the events are recorded in your Goals section:

[image]